# How do I put my resume in Google Sites?

Tags: html, google-classic-sites

How should I put my resume, created in Microsoft Word on a webpage, hosted on a Google sites, such that it looks exactly like the output from Word?

Comment: You could use a CV service like [CeeVee](http://www.ceevee.com/).

Comment: I would like to put it as a website which is very flexible. so, I don't want to use other apps.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need it to be inline (display on in a page along with other content), or is it okay to be on a separate page?

I would suggest saving your resume as a PDF (note, this is good practice in general) and ensuring that it looks good in Google's PDF previewer. You can then attach it to any page in Google sites and reference it by URL.

If you need it to be displayed in a viewer, use https://docs.google.com/viewer to generate HTML.

Alternatively, if you wish to sacrifice load speed by reducing the requirement for the user's browser to understand PDF objects, you could create a PDF and compile it to a high quality PNG using Adobe Photoshop or any number of other products. This solution is more flexible, but requires more bandwidth and processing for end user's machines, it will not work well on mobiles devices or scale well with screen size. 
My Resume, for example, is a 55KB word document, when compiled to PDF it is 102 Kb, and when compiled as a PNG at a resolution of (2381 x 3023) and compressed, it is 522Kb.

Comment: I would rather directly upload it on google sites. not a good idea

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by "directly upload it on google sites". Perhaps you can redefine the question in a more explicit manner such that it is more easily understood by all.
Is your question as follows: "How should I put my resume, created in Microsoft Word on a webpage, hosted on a Google site, such that it looks exactly like the output from Word?". 
The easiest and best solution is to create a PDF which is guaranteed to render the same on any Adobe Reader. You can save it as an image to be 'more flexible' but it is less efficient and will increase load times.

Comment: exactly.. That's what I mean

Comment: edited my question!!

Comment: I have even thought about putting it as an image but its not efficient.